# parametersLink option not passing parameters to templateLink

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I am receiving an error:

> "The value of deployment parameter 'appServiceName' is null."

Even though it is defined in the file obtained via `parametersLink`. I am never prompted so null is expected, but why am I never prompted? How do I properly pass parameters from a `parametersLink` file to a `templateLink`?

Master Template:

```
{
"$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "rgName": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Resource Group required in which to create App Service"
        }
    }
},
"variables": {},
"resources": [
    {
        "name": "LinkedAppServiceTemplate",
        "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
        "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
        "resourceGroup": "[parameters('rgName')]",
        "properties": {
            "mode": "Incremental",
            "templateLink": {
                "uri": "uri_to_template_file",
                "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
            },
            "parametersLink": {
                "uri": "uri_to_params_file",
                "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

Linked Template:

```
{
"$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {},
"variables": {},
"resources": [
    {
        "name": "[parameters('appServiceName')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
        "apiVersion": "2015-05-01",
        "location": "[parameters('rgLocation')]"
    }
]
}
```

Linked Params:

```
{
"$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "appServiceName": {
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Name of the App Service to be created"
        }
    },
    "rgLocation": {
        "defaultValue": "eastus",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Location of the resource group to be created"
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: does it work if you remove the resourceGroup property from the deployment resources (and just deploy everything to the same resourceGroup?)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the parameters in the file you've referred to as Linked Template:

Follow the [tutorial on how to create linked templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-tutorial-create-linked-templates) as it will also show you how to pass the parameter from the main template to the linked template.

In this case, your Linked Template requires a parameter declaration in the parameters object.

```
"parameters": {
    "appServiceName" : {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata" : {
            "description": "This parameter needs to exist to pass from the link file"
        }
    }
}
```